# Install Shield it needs admin privileges to run the setup

Tags: installshield-2015

Requires admin privileges for setup

I found a question about the same problem as installshield 2012 , but my problem with installshield 2015 and Solutions in the answer are not compatible with installshield 2015

I hope you understand the repetition

so

I'm trying to package application. I used install shield 2015 and I have created the setup file. When I try running the setup file it keeps throwing this error code

1925: it needs admin privileges to run the setup.

How do I configure the setup file to be run by any user? Should I make any changes in the registry during the creation of setup file in install shield? Is there anyway to work around this problem?

Comment: Are you doing things that Windows requires admin rights for, such as writing to HKCR in the registry or installing files to Program Files / Program Files (x86)?

Comment: Refer to [Per-User vs. Per-Machine Installations](https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/IHelpRunTimePerUserSetups.htm), or beef up your question with details about exactly what you're doing, what else you've tried, and what a verbose setup log says results in the 1925 error. (The message box typically lacks those details.)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, first determine whether your setup or msi should be installed with admin rights. If it doesn't need admin rights:

Set "Require Administrative Privileges" to No for the Summary Information Stream setting under General Information.

Go to your release configuration under Releases.  Select the setup.exe tab and select the Required Execution Level to Invoker.